# Angular2 NgForm valueChanges is still triggered when navigating to different page

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms

I'm working on an Angular 4.x project, and there are 2 pages with routing configured properly.

On the page1, I subscribed the valueChanges of a NgForm like this:

```
this.myNgForm1.valueChanges.subscribe(data => { 
    console.log("Is myNgForm valid ? " + this.myNgForm1.valid); 
});
```

When loading the page1, I can see "*Is myNgForm valid ? **false***".

However, when clicking the link to go to page2, I realized that the myNgForm1.valueChanges was triggered again, and now I can see "*Is myNgForm valid ? **true***"

Any idea to avoid the triggering of valueChanges of myNgForm1 when navigating to different page? Thanks!

Comment: do you use template driven form or reactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i'm aware you need to do something like this:

```
this.valueChangesSubscriber = this.myNgForm1.valueChanges.subscribe(data => { 
    console.log("Is myNgForm valid ? " + this.myNgForm1.valid); 
});
```

And then in the class add:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.valueChangesSubscriber.unsubscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy`

```
this.subscription = this.myNgForm1.valueChanges.subscribe(data => { 
    console.log("Is myNgForm valid ? " + this.myNgForm1.valid); 
});

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```